# Upload file to Google Cloud Storage using HMAC key in c#

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, hmac

I have files in a Google Cloud Storage bucket that I need to move to a customers GCS bucket.  They provided HMAC keys (access id and secret).  I'm familiar with using the c# API libraries but they require a JSON or p12 file to authenticate.  I'm not sure how to use the HMAC keys.  From my research it looks like I may need to use the GSC XML API.  Does anyone know how to authenticate using HMAC keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Suggestion #1:**

Ask the customer for a service account JSON key. Since both the source and destination bucket are in Google Cloud Storage, this is the best solution.

**Suggestion #2:**

Use AWS S3 boto libraries with AWS style Access ID and Secret to access Google Cloud Storage. Google supports AWS S3 emulation (XML API).

[AWS SDK for .NET](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/)

Comment: I went with suggestion #1.  While I was waiting for the client to respond, I was able to authenticate using the AWS SDK in suggestion #2 so I went with that route.  When using AmazonS3Client, the important config setting that needs to be set is `ServiceURL = "https://storage.googleapis.com"`